# Error Summing generic inputs create by the user

Tags: jquery, input, sum

I am trying to make a function in Jquery that allows me to add the value of 3 input (containing data expressed in time) to a 4th input , something like this:

INPUT13 INPUT12 INPUT11 INPUT14 (result) .

for this I use this function:

```
var reg1 = /^(tiempo)(1)(1|2|3)$/;
var reg2 = /^(tiempo)(2)(1|2|3)$/;
var reg3 = /^(tiempo)(3)(1|2|3)$/;
    $("input[name^='tiempo']").bind( "blur", function() {
        //alert($(this).attr('name'))
        if ( $(this).attr('name').match(reg1) ){
            $("input[name^='totalt1']").val( $("input[name^='tiempo1']").sumValues() );
        }
        if($(this).attr('name').match(reg2)){
            $("input[name^='totalt2']").val( $("input[name^='tiempo2']").sumValues() );
        }
        if($(this).attr('name').match(reg3)){
            $("input[name^='totalt3']").val( $("input[name^='tiempo3']").sumValues() );
        }
        //$("input[name^='totalt']").val( $("input[name^='tiempo']").sumValues() );
    });
```

But Inputs are dynamic, since the user can create more than one, like this:

INPUTn1 INPUTn2 INPUTn3 INPUTn4 (result) .

Function to make more Inputs is :

```
var counter = 2;
    $("#addButton").click(function () {     
        if(counter>6){
            alert("Solo se permiten 6 Mediciones por dia");
            return false;}

        $('#tiempos_te').append( '<tr>' +
            '<td><input name="fac' + counter + '" type="text" id="fac' + counter + '" onKeyPress="return acceptNum(event)" maxlength="10" class="obligatorio"/></td>' +
            '<td> <input type="text"  name="tiempo' + counter + '1" id="tiempo' + counter + '1" class="obligatorio tiempo" maxlength="6" onKeyPress="return acceptNum(event)" /></td>' +
            '<td> <input type="text" name="tiempo' + counter + '2" id="tiempo' + counter + '2" class="obligatorio tiempo" maxlength="6" onKeyPress="return acceptNum(event)" /></td>' +
            '<td> <input type="text" name="tiempo' + counter + '3" id="tiempo' + counter + '3" class="obligatorio tiempo" maxlength="6" onKeyPress="return acceptNum(event)" /></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" name="totalt' + counter + '" id="totalt' + counter + '" readonly="readonly" class="total_tiempo" /></td>' +
            '<td><select name="turn' + counter + '" id="turn' + counter + '" class="obligatorio">' +
            '<option value="2">Vespertino</option>' +
            '<option value="3">Nocturno</option>' +
            '</select></td>' +
          '</tr>' );        
        counter++;
    });
```

But new inputs do nothing, do not perform the sum, whats is happening? =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('#tiempos_te').on('blur','input[name^="tiempo"]', function(){
   // since the names are in the format "tiempo#1" where # i sa number abd the last digit is either 1,2 or 3
   // you can extract the # number by removing the "tiempo" string and also the last digit.
   var number= this.name.replace('tiempo',''), // extract the number from tiempoxxx
       counter = number.substr(0, number.length -1); // keep everything from the number except the last digit 

   // now we are left with the counter as it was used to create these fields
   $('input[name^="totalt'+counter+'"]').val ( $('input[name^="tiempo'+counter+'"]').sumValues() );
});
```

Comment: I get this error in chrome: "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on' "

Comment: @JuanJoseGutierrezAldana, what version of jQuery are you using ? (*`.on` was introduced in **v1.7***)

Comment: for earlier versions replace with `.delegate('input[name^="tiempo"]', 'blur', function(){`

Comment: From Jsquery.js: /*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.2
 * http://jquery.com/
 *
 * Copyright 2010, John Resig
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Includes Sizzle.js
 * http://sizzlejs.com/
 * Copyright 2010, The Dojo Foundation
 * Released under the MIT, BSD, and GPL Licenses.
 *
 * Date: Sat Feb 13 22:33:48 2010 -0500
 */

Comment: No Results... it no make anything, do you want all the file?

Comment: @JuanJoseGutierrezAldana can you post it on http://jsfiddle.net or http://plnkr.co/edit

Comment: @JuanJoseGutierrezAldana, you did not copy the `delegate` code as i posted it.. and also i had updated my code with some more fixes.. See http://jsfiddle.net/8XzDk/1/

Comment: @gaby-aka-g-petrioli Godness is exactly what im looking for, but can yoy explain me the code? :D and how i can do the same with data times? MM:SS ?

Comment: @JuanJoseGutierrezAldana added some comments in the answer code

Comment: @gaby-aka-g-petrioli Thx so much, now for make a sum of data times in format MM:SS how i can do?

Comment: @JuanJoseGutierrezAldana, not sure i understand what you want exactly.. you might want to ask a new question with full details on what you try to achieve..